# GoogleTest: How to set a breakpoint?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, googletest

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 C++ with Google test.  I have a post-build event on my test project to run the test project.  This works and the google test test results are displayed in the visual studio output window.  However, now I'd like to set a debug breakpoint to step through a test.  When I set a break point in either my test code or in the code it calls nothing happens.

How can I set a breakpoint with google test?  Or probably more accurately, how can I get it to trigger the debugger?

Comment: Hey, User:  So you are able to step through your application's code?

Comment: @Lucy yes I am able to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you have a separate project that builds the test. You should just run it under the debugger.

Comment: You're right can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!  I was running the googletest project as a post build event, so I would set a breakpoint and it wouldn't get triggered, but I guess that is because it was just executing the test project, not debugging it.  I right-clicked on my test project and went to Debug->Start New Instance, and voila, my breakpoint was triggered.  I think that's good enough.  Purely out of curiosity I guess I'd still be interested to know how to get the post-build event to "debug" the project rather then simply run it?

Comment: Just to add to this: in order for this to work if your test will fail, make sure in Visual Studio under Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> "On Run, when projects are out of date" is set to "Prompt to build".  And when it prompts you to build you say no.  Otherwise your project will get built and the test will fail and so your build will fail and you may not be able to get to the break point.